# Generating SSRS 2008 R2 report in C# from remote pc is slower than from local pc

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

**(Please note that this is not a first run only issue, this happens every time)**

I would like to know if anyone has come across the following.

We have created a c# application that generates reports from a SSRS instance.

When I run this application on the server where the SSRS instance resides, the report generates in +- 6 seconds.

When I run the exact same application from a remote box (same nework, just different pc to the SSRS instance), the same report takes +- 18 seconds.

The code used is something like

```
ServerReport report = new ServerReport();
report.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(reportSetup.ConnectionString);
report.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
report.ReportPath = reportName;
report.SetParameters(reportParams);
byte[] bytes = report.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

where 
`ServerReport` is from `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll` (but also tried the web version) and the rest is declared as

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string extension;
List<ReportParameter> reportParams
```

and reportSetup.ConnectionString is of the form `http://<server name>/ReportServer` (here server name is the actual name, but I have tried with IP too).

I timed each of the steps above, anf found the culprit to be on the line where it sets the parametes. So I stored the parameter values in the defaults in the actual report, and removed that step. Then the rendering just took longer than previous.

Further to that I have also tried changing the Reporting Service Configuration Manager Service Account from Network to a local account, and played around with the authentication settings in the config file (rsreportserver.config) found at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer`

Initially the authentication settings was

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

I removed the line `<RSWindowsNegotiate/>` as I read from [Authentication Types in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281310%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> **RSWindowsNegotiate**
>
> RSWindowsNegotiate directs the report server to handle authentication
>   requests that specify Negotiate. Negotiate attempts Kerberos
>   authentication first, but falls back to NTLM if Active Directory
>   cannot grant a ticket for the client request to the report server.
>   Negotiate will only fall back to NTLM if the ticket is not available.
>   If the first attempt results in an error rather than a missing ticket,
>   the report server does not make a second attempt.

but this did not help.

Does anybody have any idees on how to correct either code or SSRS installation? I would like the application to be on a sepperate server to that of the SSRS instance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have unfortunately awakened the application from sleep. For some reason bringing ssrs back online after Idle time has expired will penalize you with startup and the processes to load the environment. Once the app is back online it processes request in an expectable manner.

If you can both take wakeup out of the picture of being a problem and make the system more responsive by creating an hourly task to poll for resources.

1. Create a PowerShell  file with the following content into a script folder:

   > $wc = New-Object system.net.webClient
   >            $username = 'ReportAdmin'
   >            $password = 'ReportAdmin'
   >            $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
   >
   > ```
   > $wc.Credentials = $cred
   > $src = $wc.DownloadString(“http://<SSRSSERVERNAME>/SSRS/Pages/Folder.aspx”)
   > ```
2. Create a batch file in the script folder with this content:

> powershell -command "& 'C:\\SRSWakeup.ps1'"

1. Create a job that runs every hour and keeps ssrs alive. You can do this by saving and importing this content into the windows task manager: (It will call the .cmd to invoke the power shell command to keep ssrs alive.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> <Task version="1.2"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">  
    <RegistrationInfo>
         <Date>2012-10-29T17:57:58.8640417</Date>
         <Author>SERVER\AdminAccount</Author>
        <Description>Wakes up Reporting services when the service shuts down</Description>   </RegistrationInfo>   <Triggers>
         <CalendarTrigger>
          <Repetition>
             <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
             <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
           </Repetition>
           <StartBoundary>2012-11-01T21:06:52.4488088</StartBoundary>
           <Enabled>true</Enabled>
           <ScheduleByDay>
             <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
           </ScheduleByDay>
       </CalendarTrigger>   </Triggers>   <Principals>
         <Principal id="Author">
           <UserId>SERVER\AdminUser</UserId>
           <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
           <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
         </Principal>   </Principals>   <Settings>
         <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
         <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
         <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
         <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
         <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
         <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
         <IdleSettings>
           <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
           <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
         </IdleSettings>
        <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
         <Enabled>true</Enabled>
         <Hidden>false</Hidden>
         <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
         <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
         <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
         <Priority>7</Priority>   </Settings>   <Actions Context="Author">
         <Exec>
           <Command>C:\<ScriptFolder\wakeup.cmd</Command>
         </Exec>   </Actions> </Task>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort, but as the very first line reads **(Please note that this is not a first run only issue, this happens every time)**